# what does the number 1 in the shellescape function mean in vim?

Tags: vim

A vim command confuses me. I have read and re-read `:help shellescape()` several times. I still don't understand the meaning of the number `1` in `shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1)`.

Here's the full command I'm trying to understand:

```
:nnoremap <F4> :exe ':silent  !"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"'shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1)<CR>
```

Let's break down this long command piece by piece.

- the command is to map an exe command into F4 in the whole.
- `:exe` is to execute some  command.
- `:silent !` is to execute a shell command silently
- `"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"`  can call my firefox program.
- `shellescape()`, there are blanks to be escaped.
- `expand('%:p')` can get current file name in full expression that is path + filename.

What does this excerpt from the help page mean?

> With a |non-zero-arg| {special} and 'shell' containing "csh" in the tail it's
>           escaped a second time.

Is there some meaning such the same as 1 or 2 in `s/(ha.*)(world)/\2\1/g`?
please take a simple example in detail.

And i have two questions related to the topic.
1.In which way i can get how many type of shells in my gvim?
2.In which situation can i change `1` into `2` in shellescape()?

```
:nnoremap <F4> :exe ':silent  !"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"'shellescape(expand('%:p'), 2)<CR>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the help for `shellescape()`:

```
shellescape({string} [, {special}])          shellescape()
    Escape {string} for use as a shell command argument.
    On MS-Windows and MS-DOS, when 'shellslash' is not set, it
    will enclose {string} in double quotes and double all double
    quotes within {string}.
    For other systems, it will enclose {string} in single quotes
    and replace all "'" with "'\''".
    When the {special} argument is present and it's a non-zero
    Number or a non-empty String (non-zero-arg), then special
    items such as "!", "%", "#" and "<cword>" will be preceded by
    a backslash.  This backslash will be removed again by the :!
    command.
```

The `1` in your example simply tells `shellescape()` to escape special characters with a backslash. If you were to have (say) a `!` in the path returned by `expand()`, it’d be replaced with `\!`.

`shell` is an option:

```
                                                    'shell' 'sh' E91
'shell' 'sh'                 string (default $SHELL or "sh",
                                            MS-DOS and Win32: "command.com" or
                                            "cmd.exe", OS/2: "cmd")
                    global
    Name of the shell to use for ! and :! commands.
```

— `:help 'shell'`

“`With a non-zero-arg {special} and 'shell' containing "csh" in the tail it's escaped a second time`” means that if, as in your example, `shellescape()` is given a non-zero argument for `special` (your example has a `1`), it will check `shell` for that `"csh"`, and if it finds it (if your `shell` is set to something containing `csh`) it will double-escape it.

**EDIT** to specifically answer two questions added to (edited) original post:

1. You can get your `shell` setting (referred to in the `shellescape()` help quote) using `:echo &shell`.
2. `2` is a `Number` and is non-zero. You should therefore be able to substitute `2` for the `1` in your example and get the same result.

Comment: 1.in my system:xp+gvim ,when i input `:echo shell` , undefined varable:shell ,invalide expression:echo.2.no problem when change 1 into 2 in the shellescape().

Comment: Bah. My mistake. You are trying to get the value of `shell` and so the correct command is `:echo &shell`. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 10):

There are basically two different uses for `shellescape()`; one is the Vimscript `system()` function, the other the `:!` Ex command. While most escaping needs are identical in both uses (e.g. to deal with whitespace, arguments must be enclosed in quotes), **the `:!` command requires some additional escaping**, because on the command-line, Vim assigns special meaning to symbols like `%` (replacing it with the current file name). This does not happen for `system()`.

Therefore, to tell `shellescape()` which escaping mode to use, it has the additional `{special}` argument; if you pass `1` (or any other value that evaluates to "true"), the additional characters are escaped, too.

TL;DR: Pass `1` for `:!` commands, `0` or omit the argument for use with `system()`.