# how to write user-defined command in gvim?

Tags: php, vim

I have installed wamp stack in Windows XP, run PHP file in such steps.

1. open Vim to edit
2. save it
3. run it in brower – Firefox

I have mapped it F8 in my `_vimrc`.

```
map <F8> :call Run() <cr>
function Run()
  :cd  C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.24-0\apache2\htdocs\test
  :w  temp.php
  :silent  !"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  http://localhost/test/temp.php
endfunction
```

It can run successfully. Now I want to create a `runphp` command. When I input

```
:runphp file1.php
```

in command mode in Vim, it will do such things.

1. write the current file in `C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.24-0\apache2\htdocs\test`
2. name it as `file1.php`
3. open http://`localhost`/test/file1.php in Firefox silently

How can I write the user-defined command in Vim?
How to revise it? why the target is not "http://`localhost`/test/" add fname?
Vim will not parse target into right file.

```
function Runphp(fname)
    :cd  C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.24-0\apache2\htdocs\test
    :w!  fname
    :let target ="http://`localhost`/test/" . fname
    :silent  !"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  target
endfunction
command! -nargs=1  Runphp call Runphp(<f-args>)
```

I have write as the following, where `undefined varible fname`?

`_vimrc`:

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
set number
set langmenu=en_US
set fileencodings=utf-8,gb2312,gbk,gb18030
set termencoding=utf-8
set encoding=prc
let $LANG = "en_US"
set nowrap
set guioptions+=b
set modifiable
set write
source $VIMRUNTIME/delmenu.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim
behave mswin
set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function MyDiff()
    let opt = '-a --binary '
    if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
    if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
    let arg1 = v:fname_in
    if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
    let arg2 = v:fname_new
    if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
    let arg3 = v:fname_out
    if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
    let eq = ''
    if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
        if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
            let cmd = '""' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
            let eq = '"'
        else
            let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
        endif
    else
        let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
    endif
    silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3 . eq
endfunction

function Runphp(fname)
    cd  C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.24-0\apache2\htdocs\test
    execute 'w!' . fnameescape(a:fname)
    let target ="http://localhost/test/" . filename
    silent execute '!"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"' shellescape(target, 1)
endfunction
command! -nargs=1  Runphp call Runphp(<f-args>)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: `:help :command` tells you everything you ned to know about creating commands in Vim.

Answer (score 2):

Vim's evaluation rules are different than most programming languages. You need to **use `:execute`** in order to evaluate the variable; otherwise, it's taken literally; i.e. Vim uses the variable name itself as the argument.

Additionally, especially as [you've already asked about shellescape()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224865/what-does-the-number-1-in-the-shellescape-function-mean-in-vim), you need to **use the escaping functions**, or filenames / commands with special characters won't work.

A function argument needs to be referenced with the **`a:` sigil** inside a function.

Lastly, you don't need to prepend the `:` to commands in a function; it's only necessary interactively, to enter command-line mode.

```
function Runphp(fname)
    cd  C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.24-0\apache2\htdocs\test
    execute 'w!' . fnameescape(a:fname)
    let target ="http://localhost/test/" . fname
    silent execute '!"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"' shellescape(target, 1)
endfunction
command! -nargs=1  Runphp call Runphp(<f-args>)
```

Comment: something wrong in `execute 'w!' . fnameescape(a:fname)`,i don't know to revise it.

Comment: I don't know how to help you when you only say that "something wrong". Please be as precise and specific as possible.